# Change class on ng-focus in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<div class="icon fluid select" ng-init="focused = false">
   <i  ng-class="{'large svg guests icon':rooms==2, 'large svg guest icon':rooms==1,'active':focused==true}"></i>
    <label ng-click="closeCalendar();">
   <select ng-model="rooms" name="rooms"   class="fluid" name="rooms" focus-parent selecter required>
     <option value="1" ng-focus="focused = true">Einzelzimmer</option>
     <option value="2" ng-focus="focused = true">Doppelzimmer</option>
    </select>
 </label>
```

I initialized a model focused with initial value false, I want to change the value of this when an option of a select box is focused or when the selectbox is focused, I tried the above but it didnt work, how can I solve it, is that possible?

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle example of it?

Comment: @Riccardo it is just the above code, and some css, but the problem is on that, the value of rooms model change, but for the focused not http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=zJUqTnBOQO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<option>` elements cannot receive focus, only the `<select>` element can.
So you need to put the listeners on the `<select>` (don't forget to put a `blur` listener for setting `focused` back to false):

```
<select ng-model="rooms" 
        ng-focus="focused=true" 
        ng-blur="focused=false">
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/5UGtm/)**.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that you seem to be trying to use blur and focus instead of using the binding that is built into angular. So, what you are looking for is basically something like the following:

```
<i class="icon"  ng-class="{'gbp':rooms=='2', 'usd':rooms=='1'}"></i>
<select ng-model="rooms" name="rooms" class="fluid">
 <option value="1">Dollars</option>
 <option value="2">Pounds</option>
</select>
```

I changed the variable names, classes and icons to make it make sense with some icons I could find easily but the point is the same. Having `ng-model` on the select means that as soon as the selected value changes the class will change between "usd" and "gbp" (depending on what they have selected). The rest is just straight forward CSS to show the correct icon.

**SEE THE PLUNKER:** http://plnkr.co/edit/6cgHFirI2jxXIAGJ83YW?p=preview

---

**EDIT**

In order to change the class of an entire div based on the focus and blur you can use the `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` on the select much like the following:

```
<select ng-model="rooms" name="rooms" class="fluid"
        ng-focus="highlight=true" ng-blur="highlight=false">
```

Both `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` will automatically run an apply on the scope which will therefore allow you to change the class with a simple `ng-class` directive. Take the following as an example:

```
<div ng-class="{'highlight':highlight==true,'normal':highlight==false}">
```

You can see these updates to the original plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6cgHFirI2jxXIAGJ83YW?p=preview

Best of luck!

Comment: If you read the question (and the provided code) carefully, I believe the question is not about icons - it's about adding/removing the class `active` when the element receives/loses focus. Of course, leaving all that irrelevant details (extra classes/attributes) in the code kind of masks the actual issue (and makes it much harder for the answerer :)).

Comment: @ExpertSystem Got it! I'll try to edit my answer shortly here iwth that in mind. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I think `ng-class="highlight ? 'highlight' : 'normal'"` beatiful than`ng-class="{'highlight':highlight==true,'normal':highlight==false}"`